# Replace source attribute for multiple iframes within a string varaible using preg_match and str_replace

Tags: php, iframe, preg-replace, preg-match

I have the following code to replace youtube iframe with my custom string output:

```
preg_match('/iframe src="([^"]+)"/', $value, $match);
$url = str_replace('https://www.youtube.com/embed/','',$match[1]);
$url = str_replace('?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1','',$url);
return '<img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $url . '/mqdefault.jpg"/>';
```

But how do I implement the following code to some string which have multiple iframe but wrapped with other things that should stay when it returned:

```
$value = '<p style="text-align: center;"><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/YZvJZrfw5oo" width="560" height="314" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></p><p style="text-align: center;">Aut debitis debitis eius id recusandae. Eius unde beatae dicta neque numquam quod cupiditate. Vel dolor eos quia illo. Recusandae architecto aut quas nostrum earum totam exercitationem. Alias sint mollitia eaque molestias doloribus quia. Facere porro atque voluptatibus animi. Omnis nisi deleniti nisi sit rerum ratione rerum. Quis sed sit eveniet rerum repudiandae.<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/yPg0Keqif0I" width="560" height="314" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></p>';

//Which is the same as:

<p style="text-align: center;">
    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/YZvJZrfw5oo" width="560" height="314" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
    </iframe>
</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    Aut debitis debitis eius id recusandae. Eius unde beatae dicta neque numquam quod cupiditate. Vel dolor eos quia illo. Recusandae architecto aut quas nostrum earum totam exercitationem. Alias sint mollitia eaque molestias doloribus quia. Facere porro atque voluptatibus animi. Omnis nisi deleniti nisi sit rerum ratione rerum. Quis sed sit eveniet rerum repudiandae.
    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/yPg0Keqif0I" width="560" height="314" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
    </iframe>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `preg_match`, which only catches one match, you can use `preg_match_all` with a slightly different regular expression:

```
$value = '<p style="text-align: center;"><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/YZvJZrfw5oo" width="560" height="314" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></p><p style="text-align: center;">Aut debitis debitis eius id recusandae. Eius unde beatae dicta neque numquam quod cupiditate. Vel dolor eos quia illo. Recusandae architecto aut quas nostrum earum totam exercitationem. Alias sint mollitia eaque molestias doloribus quia. Facere porro atque voluptatibus animi. Omnis nisi deleniti nisi sit rerum ratione rerum. Quis sed sit eveniet rerum repudiandae.<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/yPg0Keqif0I" width="560" height="314" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></p>';

preg_match_all('/src="(?:https?:)?\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/([^?"]+)(?:\?[^"]+)?"/', $value, $matches);
```

First of all I want to highlight the different regex: Instead of **just** capturing the whole source attribute, it includes the regex group `([^?"]+)` and specifies the youtube url based on the strings you replaced in `str_replace`. Like this you can omit using `str_replace`. The group will contian only the necessary part that you need.

`preg_match_all` will save all matches of a specific group in an inner array with the groups ID as index. The value of `$matches` will be:

```
$matches = [
    [//Group 0 contains the whole match. This is what you got as well
        'src="//www.youtube.com/embed/YZvJZrfw5oo"',
        'src="//www.youtube.com/embed/yPg0Keqif0I"'
    ],
    [//This is the first group, that only contains the string that you need.
        'YZvJZrfw5oo',
        'yPg0Keqif0I'
    ]
];
```

By iterating over group 1 with `array_map(func..., $matches[1]);` you can address each video id seperately and create image tags with them.

```
$imageTags = array_map(function($videoId){
    return '<img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $videoId . '/mqdefault.jpg"/>';
}, $matches[1]);
```

The result will be an array of image tags. If you need to return a string instead an array you can combine the results with `implode`.

```
return implode('', $imageTags);
```